# how to replace .csv containg two tables data into 2-tables of mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

How to import `.csv` containing two tables data into two tables of Mysql?

Here is the query-

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE EmployeeTable WHEN EmployeeID,EmployeeDetailTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES ";
```

Answer (score 1):

As the `LOAD DATA` statement doesn't allow for individual columns to be included, I would suggest:

- create a temporary Table which contains all columns.
- import the whole file using `LOAD DATA`, see [MySQL LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
- do two individual `INSERT ... SELECT` statements with the columns you want in either one of the tables, see [MySQL INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: thanks konsolenfreddy.What you said is true.my problem is solved